# UIPickerview-Scrolling from Top

Tags: iphone, ios, scroll, uipickerview

In IOS, how is it possible to make UIPickerview start scrolling directly from the top?
(or to put it differently, is it possible to remove the blank white areas from the top and bottom?)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is impossible until now.
But when your Xib is loaded and you want to ful fill your pickerview
then automatically scroll that.

```
[pickerView selectRow:4 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```